# How to get the same data batch multiple times using TensorFlow's `tf.data` API

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Is there a way to evaluate a tensor that depends on an tf.data iterator but temporarily pause the iterator so that it returns the previous batch?

Imagine snippet below:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(5)
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
next_batch = iterator.get_next()
train_op = next_batch * 10
```

Every time I evaluate `train_op` it does so by fetching a new batch of data – which is what I want. However every N steps I'd like to do some additional stuff for debugging like evaluating accuracy on the training batch, creating a checkpoint, running things with dropout disabled etc. I'd like these operations to happen on the same data batch I have just used but I haven't found a way to *pause* `tf.data` iterator for one or multiple steps.

The obvious solution is to use placeholders instead of directly using `next_batch`. This means I have to evaluate `next_batch` first, and then feed it back to the session using `feed_dict` to evaluate `train_op`. I believe this is not recommended due to performance penalty. Is that still the case? If so what is the recommended way to deal with these cases?

**Edit**: adding pseudo code for what I'm after:

```
for step in num_steps:

    sess.run(train_op) # train_op depends on next_batch and therefore fetches new batch

    if step % N == 0:
        # I want below to run on the same batch above but acc_op also
        # depends on next_batch and therefore fetches a new batch
        acc = sess.run([acc_op, saver_op, feed_dic={keep_drop:1}])
```

Comment: Did you find the solution? Thanks.

Comment: Not really – Sorry

Comment: I just use the feedict. It doesn't harm the performance very much.

Answer (score -1):

Does not it work in following ways,

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(5)
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
next_batch = iterator.get_next()
train_op = next_batch * 10
other_ops = do_other_stuff(next_batch)

num_train_batch = 50
for ep in range(num_train_batch):
   if ep%N==0:
      _, other_stuffs = sess.run([train_op, other_ops])
   else:
      _ = ses.run(train_op)
```

and, you can feed the dropout differently each time

Comment: Mmm, don't think so. In both cases of the if statement `next_batch` will be evaluated and it'll fetch new data.

Comment: Yes. But in every N steps you will also do your other stuffs with that batch. Is not that you want?

Comment: Yes but I don't want the train_op to be evaluated when I'm doing other stuff

Comment: Then you can get it out from sess.run() under if like "other_stuffs = sess.run(other_ops)" :)

Comment: I added some pseudo code for what I'm after. Hopefully that makes a bit more clear

Comment: I don't think you can pause iterator with current dataset APIs. Try workaround as suggested if that serves your purpose. By the way, in your edited code, you are evaluating 'train_op' while doing other stuffs. Thanks

Comment: The bit inside the if-statement is what I mean by _other stuff_ and that bit doesn't evaluate train_op ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Okay it's really confusing what you want or which way you want. As you posted in your edited code section you are doing first sess.run(train_op) which is exactly same in terms of 'train_op' if you do sess.run([train_op, acc_op, saver_op, feed_dic={keep_drop:1}]). But if you do in two sess.run(..) as your code, you lose one batch of data during first sess.run(..) which is causing your problem. But if you can do in one sess.run(..) as I wrote in my answer it does no harm to 'train_op' (same effect as your code) plus you have all your other stuffs done.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, running [train_op, acc_op, saver_op], feed_dict={keep_drop:1} is not the same as running train_op and then the rest with dropout deactivated, because in your proposition, the train_op is ran with keep_drop:1, which is undesired during training. We don't want to skip dropout during training every N iterations.